# How to keep long text on one line without spreading it into more than 1 rows in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, textbox, textview

I have a span element that is suppoesd to keep only text inside of it. The text is being generated dynamically So I don't know how long as width the portion of text is going to be. The main thing is that I want to keep the text on one and the same line(not few) if the text width is longer that then span width.

In other words: If I had span with the width: 500, how could I make the whole text I have written so far in the question(for an examlpe) to fit inside of it and spin somehow or whatever? I just want to always to be on same line but not to go on 2 or 3 lines so it could fit the width of the container. Maybe I have to shrink it or something else. Hope you got it!

Comment: Not possible using only CSS AFAIK

Comment: you can calculate with js or jq http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: @A.Wolff I don't really know what CSS AFAIK is.

Comment: @mathinvalidnik AFAIK means: "as far as i know" sorry, should have explain it better

Comment: @OlafDietsche you mean with other tag than CSS, right?! That's true, if OP is looking for CSS only solution, he shouldn't tag it using javascript/jquery

Comment: Okay, CSS, JavaScript, Jquery. I am just wondering how that could happen. I don't really care what I am going to be using to achieve it.

Comment: @A.Wolff No, I misunderstood mathinvalidnik's comment. I thought, he doesn't know what CSS is, my fault.

Comment: It is possible. But I don't know how browser compatible it is.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible only with CSS and HTML if you use the `whitespace` and `overflow` CSS attributes.

Here's an example:

CSS:

```
.my {
    width: 120px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.my2 {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="my">
    <div class="my2">
    </div>
    <p>asdf</p>
    <p>asdf</p>
    <p>asdf</p>
</div>
```

JS to fill the my2 div:

```
var text = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    text.push('asdf');
}

$('.my2').text(text.join(' '));
```

Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7vJXK/

For scrolling text try marquee: http://jsfiddle.net/7vJXK/1/

I only tested it in Chrome though.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I don need the scroll. I just need it to be going from right to left somehow, automatically if the container width is less than the text line-width.

Comment: @mathinvald from a usability perspective that's really bad practice. But try the marquee tag. I updated my answer.

Comment: @schilingel Wow, that is exactly what I was aiming. Can you tell me more why is it a bad practice?

Comment: @mathinvalidnik because the user can't control what part of text is shown. He could miss a piece of text and would have to wait for the text to scroll over again.